Rank measurement positive and negative data POWER BI
I have a measure to generate a ranking on the clients, I need it to take into account the positive and negative values, with the measure I have I manage to take both values ​​but the rank value is not correct, instead of going 1,2,3 ,...etc., starts with 2 ,145,146,...,etc.
I add the measurement and the data sample that I have as well as the output obtained.
I hope you can help me. Thanks ¡¡
  Top N Customer = 

  VAR PositiveRanks =
    RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(SPEND_ANALYSIS[Customer Name]),
        [Amount] >= 0
    ),
    [Amount],
    ,
    DESC
)
  VAR MaxPositiveRank = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL(SPEND_ANALYSIS[Customer Name]), [Amount] >= 0))
  RETURN
    IF([Amount] >= 0,
    PositiveRanks,
    MaxPositiveRank + RANKX(
        FILTER(
            ALL(SPEND_ANALYSIS[Customer Name]),
            [Amount] < 0
        ),
        [Amount],
        ,
        DESC
    )
  )



Why do you use separate calculation for positive and negative figures? I think you can make this over whole table.

Can you please share your model and some input data?
